# 2004 Honda Civic Instrument Cluster Lights Don't Stay On

Tags: honda, civic, lights, dashboard

My 2004 Honda Civic instrument cluster lights don't work when I turn my headlights on. With the key in the ignition and the car started, the cluster lights work fine. When I turn my headlights on from there, the instrument cluster lights turn off. One of my friends said to change the whole instrument cluster. Any suggestions?

Comment: All bulbs work cause when I turn ignition on panel lights all come on soon as I turn lights on then it goes off

Comment: Your question is kind of confusing to follow.  "lights don't work when I turn lights on only thing can see is millage temp & fuel gauge lights up but can't see the needle for them also able to see the dots when change gear but when I start it everything lights up fine" If everything lights up fine when you start the car, then what's the problem?

Comment: You sure the dimmer switch isn't just all the way down?

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can just change the bulbs in the cluster. The bulbs are in little holders which twist-lock into the back of the cluster. They are quite easy to change.

To get to these, you'll need to remove the fascia in front of the cluster, then there are three screws holding the cluster in (two along the bottom, one top center). Then there will be two wiring harness connectors (one green, one blue) along the top you'll need to release. After that, the cluster should come right out. You'll see two twist-lock colors located in the back. The black twist-locks are for the idiots lights, while the white ones are for illumination.

The type of light you'll need is a [T5 dash light](https://www.google.com/#q=t5+dash+light+bulb) and are relatively inexpensive. Since you are doing it anyway, now may be a good time to move these bulbs to an LED style, or if you really get funky, you could also change the color of the bulbs as well. There are lots of options.

For a decent rundown on this procedure, check out [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/gyq5klz0O_g).

Comment: Thank you but yea all bulbs work jst when I turn lights on only certain bulbs go on

Comment: @Brad - I have no clue what you're asking, then. If the lights don't work, when you turn the lights on, what else could be going on but *the lights don't work*. Maybe you could rewrite you question and explain better what's going on?

Comment: @Paulster2 I studied his comments a little more closely and believe to have edited his question to convey his problem a little better. Sounds to me like his dimmer switch is just turned all the way down...

Comment: @DaltonD - Good deal, thanks for the edit. I would wonder why some work and some don't, though.

Comment: @Paulster2 Yeah, I thought about that too. I don't have near enough intimate knowledge of Civic instrument clusters to know exactly how the dimmer switch affects them. Hopefully OP responds with some more info.